# OpenFileMapping access denied in some exes

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I have a program that writes a variable using

```
CreateFileMapping (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE , 0, sizeof(data), "Local\\testtest");
```

And then I have dll that is loaded into firefox's plugin-container.exe (running as locally logged on user) that calls

```
OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ,  FALSE, "Local\\testtest");
```

And this works fine.  However when I try the same thing with my dll loaded into iexplore.exe( also running as locally logged on user) I get a NULL value and GetLastError returns (0x5) ACCESS DENIED.

I tried adjusting the privileges of the process in the dll to add SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME however this made no difference ( and I didn't expect it to since the permission is only required to make a global Name I believe and not a Local one which im using).

No matter what I try , with iexplore.exe it fails with ACCESS DENIED.  The only 1 way around it I have found is to run my setter program as administrator AND run iexplore.exe as administrator and then it is able to read it.  But I don't see this as a solution because I really want to avoid having to run the entire exe under administrator.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Tried explicitly setting the permissions on the mapping?

Comment: Did you mean setting lpAttributes in createfilemapping() ?  I havent tried that i will look into using that now.

Comment: no dice on this one unfortunately, I tried setting it but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: What OS?  Perhaps IE is running in protected mode and the integrity levels prevent you from accessing it.

Comment: Yes you are right looks like it has to do with this protected mode.  I am trying to use registry instead now.

Comment: @skimon could you please share with us what you eventually found out?

Comment: @OmerRaviv I discovered that the technique i tried above only works if the application/plugin container is running with enough permission initially.  It worked flawlessly on firefox (perhaps plugin-container was running at near administrator level ) but not on chrome or IE.  If however I ran chrome or IE as adminstrator then it worked on those browsers too.  I gave up on this approach as I could not expect users to run the browser as administrator.  Instead I opted to use a hidden window -CreateWindow() in the DLL and then PostMessage to send it messages from my main app.

Comment: Thanks, this post helped me solve my issue. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

If the security is not of an issue but just want to make it work, you can also set DACL of file mapping to be NULL which will then give full access to everyone.

Following is an example.

```
SetSecurityInfo(handle, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, 
    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But please understand that this is not recommended if you concern security.

Comment: @istudy0 To clarify, does the server call `SetSecurityInfo` on its own copy of the handle? Because you can't do it on the client's since the stated problem is that `OpenFileMapping` doesn't return one.

Comment: Figured it out by trying it: yes, the server calls `SetSecurityInfo`, as shown in this answer, on its own handle. Works like a charm. +1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exchange memory or use synchronize resources of system(mutexes, semaphores...) in other system sessions(different OS's users start your processes), you need to do 2 steps:

In generative process:

1. Create objects with reset Dacl properties.
2. Create objects with prefix("Global")
   If you create object without first step, you will get error Access Denied. If you create one without second step, you will get error File not found.

In process, which uses resources:

1. Open objects with prefix("Global") too.

Follow code works in Windows 10 and demonstrates details:

```
    // prepare kernel synchronization objects
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSessionSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
if (!pSessionSD)
{
    ERR(TEXT("LocalAlloc error."));
}
if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSessionSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
{
    ERR(TEXT("InitializeSecurityDescriptor error."));
}
if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSessionSD, TRUE, NULL, FALSE))
{
    ERR(TEXT("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl error"));
}

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSessionSD;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

// Multithread memory 
HANDLE hFileMapping;
hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, sa, PAGE_READWRITE, size.HighPart, size.LowPart, "Global\\MyMemoryFile.mem");
......
LocalFree(pSessionSD);
```