# MapViewOfFile returns Error 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, shared

I'm trying to develop a system that uses shared memory for communication between two processes. One process is a 32 bit application and uses a 32bit dll for the communication. The other process is a 64 bit application and uses a 64 bit dll which contains the exact same code for creating/opening the shared memory. I made it so whenever one process opens a handle to the memory and cannot open it, it automatically tries to create the memory. The other process will then try the same so whichever process runs the code first will create the memory while the other process will open a handle to the already existing memory.

The code works absolutely fine when the shared memory is created by the 64 bit process/dll but whenever the 32 bit dll creates it, I get error 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) returned when calling MapViewOfFile.

I already checked if the size that I pass to any of the functions is different, for example because one of the structures has a different size depending on if it was compiled for 32 bit or 64 bit. However, this is not the case, the size is always the same in both processes.

I also tried the code that was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5689496/5407251) answer without success.
Does anyone have an idea why the code sometimes fails with error 5?

Here is my code:

```
static LPVOID lpMappedInputData = nullptr,
    lpMappedOutputData = nullptr;

static HANDLE hInputFileMapping = NULL,
    hOutputFileMapping = NULL;

HANDLE createOrOpenFileMapping(DWORD size, LPCSTR lpName)
{
    HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, lpName);

    if (!hMapFile)
        DEBUG_LOG("OpenFileMapping failed! Error code: %i - Attempting to create the file mapping instead...\n", GetLastError());

    if (!hMapFile)
    {
        hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, lpName);

        if (!hMapFile)
            DEBUG_LOG("CreateFileMapping failed! Error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return hMapFile;
}

LPVOID mapViewOfFile(HANDLE hFileMappingObject, DWORD size)
{
    LPVOID lpMappedData = MapViewOfFile(hFileMappingObject, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, size);

    if (!lpMappedData)
    {
        CloseHandle(hFileMappingObject);
        DEBUG_LOG("MapViewOfFile failed! Error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return lpMappedData;
}

bool Initialize()
{
    DEBUG_LOG("Initializing the input file mapping...\n");

    hInputFileMapping = createOrOpenFileMapping(sizeof(InputData), "Local\\InputData");

    if (!hInputFileMapping)
        return false;

    lpMappedInputData = mapViewOfFile(hInputFileMapping, sizeof(InputData));

    if (!lpMappedInputData)
        return false;

    DEBUG_LOG("Initializing the output file mapping...\n");

    hOutputFileMapping = createOrOpenFileMapping(sizeof(OutputData), "Local\\OutputData");

    if (!hOutputFileMapping)
        return false;

    lpMappedOutputData = mapViewOfFile(hOutputFileMapping, sizeof(OutputData));

    if (!lpMappedOutputData)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void Deinitialize()
{
    DEBUG_LOG("Deinitializing the file mappings...\n");

    if (lpMappedInputData)
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpMappedInputData);

    if (hInputFileMapping)
        CloseHandle(hInputFileMapping);

    if (lpMappedOutputData)
        UnmapViewOfFile(lpMappedOutputData);

    if (hOutputFileMapping)
        CloseHandle(hOutputFileMapping);

    DEBUG_LOG("Successfully deinitialized the file mappings!\n");
}
```

Comment: Bitness plays no role, you need to focus on the user accounts or privilege escalation that control these processes.  Details you did not provide in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant so what do you suggest me to do? Both processes run under the exact same user account.

Comment: Try with just a standard pathname to a file and see if the problem goes away.  I am worried what "WOW64" (the x86 emulator that allows 32-bit Windows-based applications to run) does with "Local\\"  . Even though it's the same user it's a different security context (i think).

Comment: @RichardCritten that still doesn't explain why it works when one process creates the memory, but not when the other one does so. If the path would be different like you said, it should never work no matter what process creates the memory first, should it?

Comment: But it's quick to test and prove me wrong.  I did say "Try" not "This is the problem".  Sometimes solving these issues is a process of elimination. And an emulation layer with file redirection need to be eliminated.

Comment: @RichardCritten It actually works when I use files instead of what I did before. But how can I fix the problem without using files?

Comment: at first you not need call `OpenFileMapping` - you can do single call to `CreateFileMapping` - it creates or opens. at second - instead `GetLastError` - call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` on fail - this give much more information about fail reason

Comment: `InputData` - this is what ? I guess it have different size in x64 and x86

Comment: @RbMm Please read what I already wrote when I explained my problem. I checked the sizes of all structures that I'm using and they DO match in x64 and x86 so this is not the issue. I basically have two different structures that contain different data. For each of them I create a seperate memory region.

Comment: @ccman32 - please do what I say - call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` - I almost sure that error was - `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE` and post definition of `InputData` - I almost sure that in 32bit it have smaller size compare 64

Comment: @RbMm The error I'm getting is 0xC000001F. Here is a definition of the structure: https://pastebin.com/A79cnnZG

Comment: so I was correct at begin - size is smaller in 32bit - what is `OutputData`? (`c000001f == STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`  how I and guess)

Comment: @RbMm When I log sizeof(..) for both structures in 32 bit and 64 bit it logs the exact same size in both cases. How is this possible when the size would actually be different? Anyway, this is the OutputData struct: https://pastebin.com/KhUCCKx4

Comment: and what concrete `sizeof(OutputData)` in 32 and 64 bit process ?

Comment: @RbMm https://i.gyazo.com/0c7e36db8484b011627152f2a42c61d4.png

Comment: @RbMm Thats not true, 0x50008+0x5008 is 0x55010 which is 348176 and that is exactly what I can see in my debug output. Any other idea?

Comment: You file mapping object names are *very* generic, and may collide with other objects. If you want unique names, use the string representation of a GUID, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable I changed them for this thread/question. In reality they are a lot less generic.

Comment: Note that calling `CloseHandle()` **before** you call `GetLastError()` is a mistake. Always save the error code as soon as an API function fails, as calling other API functions can modify the error code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - in practice no - `CloseHandle` not change last error/ntstatus if not fail. error here definitely  `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`. but code how I view not relevant, based on what OP say in comments. exist something else, invisible in this code, which affect result. OP say about some unclear raise condition (error "only in case when run 2 process too quickly")

Comment: here real error - double `CloseHandle` call - inside `mapViewOfFile` and than in `Deinitialize`

Comment: @RbMm In practice, very much yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win32 errors - this is in most cast translated from original `NTSTATUS` native api call result. but this translation is not injective - sometimes many different status converted to the same win32 error value. for example to the same `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` converted  at least 18(!) different ntstatus. so original error can be not `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` but absolute another, having nothing common to real access denied. because this, if win32 api call is shell over native call - always better call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` for get original error status code or call native api direct (`ZwMapViewOfSection` instead `MapViewOfFile`)

unfortunately I don't know original status returned by `ZwMapViewOfSection`, but I guess that this is `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE` (*An attempt was made to create a view for a section which is bigger than the section.*).

in create and map section used `sizeof(InputData)` and `sizeof(OutputData)` - no definitions of this structures in code, bat based on

> The code works absolutely fine when the shared memory is created by
>   the 64 bit process/dll but whenever the 32 bit dll creates it, I get
>   error 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) returned when calling `MapViewOfFile`.

I guess next - in 32bit code `InputData` or `OutputData` have smaller size )compare 64 bit code). this just explain all. if 64 bit code first create section and then 32 bit code try map smaller size - this is ok. but if 32 bit code first create section and then 64 bit code try map size bigger that section size - we got `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE` which translated to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

but how about

> I already checked if the size .. the size is always the same in both
>   processes.

not believe. I be recheck.

as separate note - the [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Creates or **opens** a named or unnamed file mapping object for a
>   specified file.

so we not need special function `createOrOpenFileMapping` and call `OpenFileMappingA` first - just call `CreateFileMappingW` (for what use `A` api ?). and any way code of `createOrOpenFileMapping` have raise condition - both processes can call `OpenFileMappingA` in concurrent and both fail here. that both anyway call `CreateFileMappingA`

but main `GetLastError()` some times not the best and `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` not always is `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` and related to real access denied error

Comment: As I already mentioned in my comment, RtlGetLastNtStatus returns 0xC000001F (STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE). However, when I check sizeof for both structures from the 32 bit and from the 64 bit application I get the same size in both cases: https://i.gyazo.com/0c7e36db8484b011627152f2a42c61d4.png

How is this possible?

Comment: To avoid the problem you mentioned when both processes call OpenFileMappingA in concurrent, what should I do instead? I can't think of any better solution and this must work no matter which process executes the code first.

Comment: Answers must provide a solution.  I do not feel like this provides a solution

Comment: @dtracers - and what you fill interesting ? answer explain all. solution is simply - use the same size, if you not understand this yet :)

Comment: @ccman32 - *when both processes call OpenFileMappingA in concurrent* - but explain that this is senseless call in your case at all. simply call `CreateFileMappingW`

Comment: @RbMm  It seems you have not provided a solution to use the same size.  You are just saying hey you have an error if you fix the error then you no longer have an error.
But that is not a viable solution or a path forward for this person

Comment: @dtracers - I give the perfect explanations what is happens really (when another commentators guess that  *Bitness plays no role* and guess that here really access denied case). based on my explanations very easy understand what need fix - the size.

Comment: @RbMm Yeah I already changed it, now it only calls CreateFileMapping. Also I just figured out that my code works just fine when it is executed only in the 32bit process and then in the 64 bit process. The error STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE only occurs when I first start the 32 bit process and then immediately the 64 bit one. Any idea? This seems pretty weird to me...

Comment: @ccman32 - why in your screenshot in both size `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`  are both 32 and 64 bit fail ?

Comment: @RbMm They both fail when trying to call MapViewOfFile but CreateFileMapping is called successfully.

Comment: @ccman32 I have not your binary code for debug and say exactly. but I explain you src of error - you use different size in create and map request

Comment: @ccman32 - also really in memory section size aligned up to page size. look like you in your 32 bit dll serious confuse size passed to call create section

Comment: @RbMm I pass sizeof(InputData) and sizeof(OutputData) in both cases. I am absolutely 100% sure that the sizes are all identical for 32 bit and 64 bit no matter what that returned error is saying. I do believe that this is a timing related problem because when I run both processes with some delay, the code always works no matter if I run the 32 bit or the 64 bit process first.

Comment: @ccman32 - dbgprint `size` passed to calls `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` as is with result of call, error status and bitness . and please in hex not in dec

Comment: @ccman32 - *timing related problem* - how time related to section size ? or you not show all picture

Comment: @RbMm It isn't related to section size. As you can see in my debug logs, the MapViewOfFile call fails in BOTH processes. It even fails when I hardcode the sizes so I know for absolutely sure that they are identical for both calls. There is absolutely no way the size differs for the 32 bit and the 64 bit process. I have proven this with debug logs and by replacing them with hardcoded values. This is NOT the problem.

Comment: @ccman32 - can only repeat - *dbgprint size passed to calls CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile as is with result of call, error status and bitness . and please in hex not in dec*

Comment: @ccman32 - if it fail in both - look like you in 32bit dll pass error size to call `CreateFileMapping`. print not size of structure but actual size passed to api call. and in **hex**

Comment: @ccman32 - if you run 32 bit exe **separate** - you anyway got `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE` ? and if you run 64bit exe separate - all will be ok ? I correct understand ?

Comment: @ccman32 - also you must print `GetLastError` after `CreateFileMapping` - are it 0 or `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. your problem first of all in debugging - how separate and reproduce and locate error case.

Comment: @RbMm When I run the 32 bit exe, it will initialize successfully. When I then run the 64 bit exe, it will also initialize successfully. Only when I run the 32 bit exe and then immediately also run the 64 bit exe then I get this error on both of them. When I first run the 64 bit exe and then immediately the 32 bit one it also works fine.

Comment: @ccman32 - again - this say that you bad in debugging. set say `MessageBox` before calls to `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`. detect exactly sequence when it failed.

Comment: @RbMm The sequence does NOT matter. When I run it in the exact same sequence it will fail when I do it quickly (running both processes automated from code directly one after another) and succeed when there is some delay between starting the processes. The only difference is the timing.

Comment: @ccman32 - no, sequence is matter. you not want listen me. set messageboxex for control what api called first in what process. this is not time problem. this is not access denied problem. this is size problem. only you can locate error just now in your code. *to quicly* - say nothing. if you code unconditional call `CreateFileMapping+MapViewOfFile` just - one exe always call both it before you can run another. or you something sensitive not say. anyway set messageboxex for manual set order of calls and locate error case

Comment: @ccman32 - your code very far from Complete and **Verifiable** example - impossible say exactly what you really doing in code. but anyway I explain you that your error was not access denied but mismatch section size. and time here also not related (too or not too quickly). only section size. but how many sections, in what order you create or **open** what you do else - all this not visible from your question. you must debug and locate problem

Comment: @RbMm what do you mean? I already posted my entire code before, there is nothing else going on which i'm hiding here. Yes, my code did change a bit depending on your suggestions and things you told me to try. I can post an updated version of the entire code later after my work shift if that would help. I will include more details later but there really isnt much else to say.

Comment: @ccman32 your code not Verifiable example which not let reproduce what you say in comments. absolute unclear what you mean about time (too quickly). I give your perfect advice - use messagebox before calls CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile for control order. print also getlasterror after `CreateFileMapping` for view are section created or opened. post exactly call order with log results, when fail. use not 2 section (input-output) but one.

Comment: @RbMm I will try so later and let you know the results.

Comment: @RbMm I figured out what was wrong. We created the shared memory with python code/methods before in an older version and forgot to remove the old python code. Therefore the python code created the shared memory with a smaller size (the structures changed since the old version) and caused this problem.

Comment: @ccman32 - if you will be check last error for `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` after `CreateFileMapping` (log it) - you faster resolve this. and main - some times use `RtlGetLastNtStatus` give much more relevant info compare `GetLastError`

Comment: @RbMm yeah and I did not know about RtlGetLastNtStatus before, thanks!